# Compatibility/ Documentation with ML.NET on MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ml.net

I've read online and watched some videos concerning `ML.NET` and the usage of it. All the videos and documentation that I've read online were on `ASP.NET` Core. I was wondering if it was possible to use the `ML.NET` on `MVC5` (Since that's what we've been taught in class and have to use for our project)

If it is compatible are there any links or suggestions on how to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

ML.NET requires .NET Core in version 2.1 (or newer) or .NET Framework version 4.6.1 (or newer):

> First, ensure you have installed .NET Core 2.1 or later. ML.NET also works on the .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later, but 4.7.2 or later is recommended.

[Source: GitHub page for ML.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning)

As long as your app is running on one of those .NET implementations, you should be good to go. Regardless of the app type (ASP.NET, Winforms, ...).

You can find samples [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples).